# FindById & FindOne do not work on IDs or usernames that I get from Angular Local Storage

Tags: angular, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-populate, angular-local-storage

I'm making a courier system, in which one franchise needs to dispatch a package to another franchise. User inputs the name of the franchise the package needs to go & I'm fetching the ID & storing in "dispatchedTo". While I'm getting the ID of "dispatchedBy", from Angular localStroage where I saved it when the user(Franchise) logged into the system. But findById, findOne or even find are not working when applied on attributes fetched from localStorage.

```
    //This Part Does not return franchise... franchise object is empty
    let franchise = await Franchise.findById(req.body.dispatchedBy);
        if(!franchise){
            return res.json({error: {message: "Origin Not Found!"},});
        }
    //This part work... franchise1 is the right object
        let franchise1 = await Franchise.findById(req.body.dispatchedTo);
        if(!franchise1){
            return res.json({error: {message: "Destination Not Found!"},});
        }
```

MongoDB saves the record with ID of both 'dispatchedBy' & 'dispatchedTo':
 {"_id":"5c1fdcd0dc5ce60e8c856ca1","dispatchedBy":"5c1c06c2f458b617506f1ac1","dispatchedTo":"5c1de40419975e0a6c224d6a","dispatchedOn":"2018-12-23T19:03:50.997Z","receivedOn":"2018-12-23T19:03:50.997Z","packet":"5c1ea84ca706ba112c9dbe9e","dispatchStatus":"DisJanu","user":"Sohail","__v":0}

However, when I apply populate then 'dispatchedBy' returns null.

```
router.get('/', async(req, res)=>{
const dispatch = await Dispatch.find().sort('dispatchedOn').populate('packet', 'packetNumber _id').populate('dispatchedBy', 'title _id').populate('dispatchedTo', 'title _id');
return res.json(dispatch);
```

});

Any possible fix?

Answer (score 0):

So `findById` just filters only on the basis of the `_id` field. You can try `findOne` like

```
Franchise.findOne({ dispatchedBy: req.body.dispatchedBy });
Franchise.findOne({ dispatchedTo: req.body.dispatchedTo });
```

Comment: Nimish! I've tried findOne as well, returns null.
I'm fetching dispatchedBy from localStorage, and findOne, find or findbyId is not working with dispatchedBy.
I tried this: store username & password of a user in localStorage then try to authenticate by retrieving username & password from localStorage & again mongoose is unable to find the user.
It must be Angular localStorage, I'm pulling my hair now.

Comment: Hey Nimish! I'v found the issue. I was logged in as a user with different role :(
I was logged in as Admin instead of Franchise :(